# How to detect button press on Adafruit NRF52840

Tags: arduino, gpio, adafruit

I am using a Feather Express NRF52840 and am trying to make use of the presupplied user button.

*[Reading the pinout](https://learn.adafruit.com/introducing-the-adafruit-nrf52840-feather/pinouts)* says:

> A tactile switch is provided for use in your projects, which is connected to P1.02 and is accessible in code as D7 in Arduino and SWITCH in CircuitPython.

I am using [example code](https://learn.adafruit.com/make-it-switch/debouncing) to read the button's state change.

The problem I am having is that the code will not compile when I use D7 rather than A1 in the original code. The error I get is:

```
sketch_nov04a:1:23: error: 'D7' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'A7'?
    1 | const int buttonPin = D7;   // the number of the pushbutton pin
      |                       ^~
      |                       A7
exit status 1
'D7' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'A7'?
```

I considered using A7 thinking the error message might be right but reading the pinout, AREF (A7/P0.31) is already in use.

What am I missing?

```cpp
const int buttonPin = D7;   // the number of the pushbutton pin
int buttonState;            // the current reading from the input pin
int lastButtonState = HIGH; // the previous reading from the input pin

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(100);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  int reading = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  if (reading != lastButtonState) {
    Serial.println("I ATE THE PIE!!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```cpp
const int buttonPin = 7;
```

There are probably macros defining A0 etc., but as far as I know there aren't any for D0 etc.; for those you just use the number, without the "D".